# Read a property file and get value in .sh

Tags: shell, sh

I know how to read a file and get all text but i need to know how to get only the value i need.

ex:-

.properties file has,

```
runId=A667B
```

I just need to get A667B value.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
awk -F= '$1=="runId"{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
. .properties
```

Thereafter, the value can be obtained through `$runId`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure-shell method:

```
IFS="=" read -r ignore var <file.properties
```

After executing the above the variable `var` has the value `A667B`.

The above works by reading in to variables from the file.  Normally, the shell expects variables to be separated by whitespace.  However, in this case, we tell it that the variables will be separated by an equal sign.  We do this by assigning the `IFS` variable to have the value of `=`.

The `-r` option to `read` tells it to treat any backslashes in the input file as literal backslashes, not as characters with special meaning.  If you want the special meanings, like `\t` being tab, then remove that option.

The above also sets the shell variable `ignore` to have the value `runId`.  Since you said you didn't want that, just ignore the variable named `ignore`.

The double quotes in the code above are actually unnecessary.  I put them there to try to make the code more clear.  The following line may look strange but it works just as well:

```
IFS== read -r ignore var <file.properties
```